Passing UTF-8 arguments to commands in Perl on Windows
I am trying to build a template for Perl scripts so that they would do at least most of the basic things right with UTF-8 and would work equally well on Linux and Windows machines.
One thing in particular escaped me for a while: the difficulty of passing UTF-8 strings as arguments to system commands. It seems to me that there is no way not to have arguments double UTF-8 encoded before they reach the shell (that is, I understand that there is a layer that ignores that the command and its arguments are already properly UTF-8 encoded, takes it for Latin-1 or something of the sorts, and encodes it again as UTF-8). I could not find a way to cleanly avoid this layer of encoding.
Take this script:
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.14;

use utf8;
use feature 'unicode_strings';
use feature 'fc';
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
use strict;
use warnings;
use warnings FATAL => 'utf8';

use constant IS_WINDOWS => $^O eq 'MSWin32';

# Set proper locale
$ENV{'LC_ALL'} = 'C.UTF-8';

# Set UTF-8 code page on Windows
if (IS_WINDOWS) {
  system("chcp 65001 > nul 2>&1");
};

# Use Win32::Unicode::Process on Windows
if (IS_WINDOWS) {
  eval {
    require Win32::Unicode::Process;
    Win32::Unicode::Process->import;
  };
  if ($@) {
    die "Could not load Win32::Unicode::Process: $@";
  };
};


# Show the empty directory
print "---\n" . `ls -1 system*` . "---\n";

my $utf = "test-тест-מבחן-परीक्षण--";

# Works fine on Linux but not on Windows
print "System (touch) exit code: " . system("touch system-$utf > touch-system.txt 2>&1") . "\n";
print "System (echo) exit code: " . system("echo system-$utf > echo-system.txt 2>&1") . "\n";

if (IS_WINDOWS) {
  # Works fine on Windows
  print "SystemW (touch) exit code: " . systemW("touch systemW-$utf > touch-systemW.txt 2>&1") . "\n";
  print "SystemW (echo) exit code: " . systemW("echo systemW-$utf > echo-systemW.txt 2>&1") . "\n";
};

# Show the directory with the new the files
print "---\n" . `ls -1 system*` . "---\n";

exit;

On Linux, everything is fine: the file created with touch through system() has a UTF-8 encoded filename and the content of the file created with echo is correctly UTF-8 encoded.
Yet, I found no way to get the same code to behave correctly on Windows. There, the output of the script is this:
---
---
System (touch) exit code: 0
System (echo) exit code: 0
SystemW (touch) exit code: 
SystemW (echo) exit code: 
---
system-test-Ñ‚ÐµÑÑ‚-×ž×‘×—×Ÿ-à¤ªà¤°à¥€à¤•à¥à¤·à¤£-ðŸ˜Š-ð“½ð“®ð“¼ð“½
systemW-test-тест-מבחן-परीक्षण--
---

As the script shows, the only way I could make it work is to use Win32::Unicode::Process::systemW() to replace system(). The file systemW-test-тест-מבחן-परीक्षण-- is correctly named and the content of echo-systemW.txt is correctly encoded in UTF-8.
My questions are these:

Is there a way to avoid using systemW() and keep the code identical for Linux and Windows but somehow remove this layer that double-encodes the system command? In other words, is this the only good way to go?

If this is the right way, I am not sure how to obtain the similarly correct behaviour for backticks. They have the same problem as system() but I have no idea how to capture the output of a command with systemW() aside from piping it into a temporary file and reading that at the end (possible, of course, but maybe not great).



It is a commonly known thing that making changes to the shell is ineffective, because system et al creates a new shell for each call, with default settings. You should verify your shell settings and see if they were applied.

@TLP: I cannot really tell why it is so, but I did verify this and if I add a system("chcp"); right after the system() setting the chcp, I get Active code page: 65001. Equivalently, if I do not set it to 65001, things do not work fine because my default active code page is 1252. In other words, this piece of the puzzle seems to work fine.

Avoiding systemW() for Unified Behavior on Linux and Windows: Unfortunately, Windows' cmd.exe does not natively support UTF-8 in the same way that Linux shells do. Even with chcp 65001, which sets the console code page to UTF-8, there are quirks and inconsistencies. The double-encoding issue arises because the Perl system() function and backticks (```) on Windows internally use ANSI APIs, which do not fully respect UTF-8.
To achieve consistent behavior, you must use the wide-character APIs, such as systemW() from Win32::Unicode::Process. There's no direct way around this limitation with Perl's standard system() on Windows.
Handling Backticks with Wide-Character APIs: As you've identified, Perl's backticks also rely on the ANSI API, and there's no direct equivalent of systemW() for capturing output. However, you can use the following workaround:
Use temporary files for command output, as you mentioned.
Alternatively, leverage Win32::Unicode::Process to implement a custom backtick-like behavior using wide-character APIs.


In Linux, you need to encode the command using the locale's encoding.
In Windows, you need to encode the command using the Active Code Page.

Encode::Locale's $ENCODING_LOCALE provides the correct encoding in both cases.
Example Linux run:
$ perl -Mv5.14 -MEncode::Locale -e'say $Encode::Locale::ENCODING_LOCALE'
UTF-8

Example Windows run:
>perl -Mv5.14 -MEncode::Locale -e"say $Encode::Locale::ENCODING_LOCALE"
cp1252

The encoding name for the Active Code Page is also provided by the following:
use Win32;

my $encoding = "cp".Win32::GetACP();

On Windows, this is cp1252 for many people, which would not be able to accommodate the characters you wish to encode. To encode any character, you must the Wide interface instead of the ANSI interface, which is what systemW provides.
That said, it is possible to change the encoding used by the ANSI interface on a per-program basis. See Use UTF-8 code pages in Windows apps.
